# Rails/MySQL: Different user timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, timezone

Question 1 - I have an app that is on shared hosting in Dallas, TX...so my database/web server are currently set to Central US time...I'm unable to change this, so UTC is off the table.

My application records and displays Date and Time data to the user, but every user could be in a different time zone.

If I configure my app `(config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)')`, but then I allow users to select their timezone,

```
def user_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```

will RoR display any returned data in the timezone of the user's choice?  Or do I need to evaluate the data and modify it accordingly before it is displayed?

Question 1.1 - I have related mailers that send daily/weekly/monthly reports to users.  If I run these using CRON, would I need to schedule my jobs to at different time intervals to allow for the timezones?  In other words, if one job contains

```
when 'daily'
   @dates = params[:f]['Date Range'] = "#{Date.current} - #{Date.current}"
```

Date.current will be 1 hour ahead on the East Coast, and 3 hours behind on the West and so forth.  So (still using server timezone of Central), would I run one at 11pm (for East) and one at 2am (for West)?

Any and all advice/assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question. What is the database server of your host?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best results, your application should be written such that the time zone of the computer that it is running on does not influence any data or behavior.

That usually means working in UTC in your code.  For example, `Time.now.utc` instead of just `Time.now`.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755677/634824) for details for RoR.

It is a best practice to set the server time zone to UTC when possible, but that doesn't mean you should rely on that in your code.

Regarding your second question, keep in mind that every time zone has their own concept of a "day".  See [this site](http://everytimezone.com/) for a visualization.

You should run a separate job at midnight in each time zone that you are aligning your data to.  Some applications (such as the StackExchange web sites) use a single time zone (often UTC) for all users.  Other applications adjust the data for each user according to their own time zone.  You need to decide what is appropriate for your application.

When scheduling your jobs, determine the UTC time that each time zone's midnight aligns to.  Then schedule a job for that time.  Be sure your scheduler understands that it is UTC.  Don't try to adjust it to the server's local time zone, or you might introduce error when the local time zone goes through daylight saving time transitions.

Make sure that not only does the scheduled job run at the correct time, but that the report query uses the correct time zone in determining the UTC range that it should run for.

Note that this does mean that two users from different time zones reporting over the same data may end up producing different results - because each of their "days" is for a slightly different period.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  As for the app, just so I clearly understand, the data that is stored in my DB is recorded at Central time, so in my app code, I should convert this to UTC (when called) and then adjust (+/-) to user's timezones as needed?

Comment: You should change your app to store data in the DB as UTC.  The problem with storing local times is that they can be ambiguous. For example, if you store `2013-11-03 01:00` and that's US Central Time, then there are two different possible moments in time it could refer to, due to daylight saving time ending.  [See here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=64)

Comment: If you already have production data stored in central time, then you would need to convert it when you roll out the changes.  I would suggest adding a new column for the utc time and then dropping the old one later.  Be sure to convert it as central time (`America/Chicago`), not as a fixed -5 or -6 offset.  And check for ambiguities using [`TZInfo::AmbiguousTime`](http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org/doc/TZInfo/AmbiguousTime.html).  You'll have to decide how you want to handle those ambiguities.   Of course, it will be much easier if you haven't got any production data to convert yet.

Comment: Thanks again. My challenge is that the data going into the database is from external data sources (browser plugins), and while they are configured to UTC, once they hit the database, the DB is storing them at Central time.  I guess I'll be looking into a different hosting option that will make it easy for me to manage my DB and set it to UTC.  Thanks again!

Comment: You usually have control over that.  Switching hosts isn't going to improve your code. ;)  For example, read up on the `datetime` and `timestamp` types in the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Thanks.  Its shared hosting, and they told me it can't be done.  Thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34181/discussion-between-matt-johnson-and-user464180)

Comment: You CAN change the timezone in your SQL shared hosting, see my answer bellow

Answer (score 2):

Very clear answer from Matt. You definitely want to save your time data in UTC TZ, then translate it to your user TZ (or server TZ for guests users)

You are using MySQL globally set to non-UTC TZ, you can override this setting with the following query

```
SET time_zone = 'UTC';
```

Problem is: this command is session wide in MySQL, you must set it again each time a new connection to you database is initialized. Rails ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool class can help you for that. See this answer: [How do I execute queries upon DB connection in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519413/how-do-i-execute-queries-upon-db-connection-in-rails)

Next you need to set up your server default TZ in application.rb (you did that) and set up each user to have his own TZ (and you did that as well)

Finaly you must follow Rails conventions each time you access time data. I found this article for you, full of very useful information it will answer all your question:  http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails

Extract from that article:

**DOs**

```
2.hours.ago # => Fri, 02 Mar 2012 20:04:47 JST +09:00
1.day.from_now # => Fri, 03 Mar 2012 22:04:47 JST +09:00
Date.today.to_time_in_current_zone # => Fri, 02 Mar 2012 22:04:47 JST +09:00
Date.current # => Fri, 02 Mar
Time.zone.parse("2012-03-02 16:05:37") # => Fri, 02 Mar 2012 16:05:37 JST +09:00
Time.zone.now # => Fri, 02 Mar 2012 22:04:47 JST +09:00
Time.current # Same thing but shorter. (Thank you Lukas Sarnacki pointing this out.)
Time.zone.today # If you really can't have a Time or DateTime for some reason
Time.zone.now.utc.iso8601 # When supliyng an API (you can actually skip .zone here, but I find it better to always use it, than miss it when it's needed)
Time.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').in_time_zone(Time.zone) # If you can't use Time#parse
```

**DON’Ts**

```
Time.now # => Returns system time and ignores your configured time zone.
Time.parse("2012-03-02 16:05:37") # => Will assume time string given is in the system's time zone.
Time.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') # Same problem as with Time#parse.
Date.today # This could be yesterday or tomorrow depending on the machine's time zone.
Date.today.to_time # => # Still not the configured time zone.
```

Comment: +1 for the ruby-specific information.  I know much about time zones, but little about ruby.  Thanks!